# Remove path from output

Tags: powershell, select-string

Using the following `Select-String` command in PowerShell:

```
Select-String -Path E:\Documents\combined0.txt -Pattern "GET /ccsetup\.exe" -AllMatches > E:\Documents\combined3.txt
```

creates an output file with each line starting with the path and file name followed by a colon. For example:

```
E:\Documents\combined0.txt:255:255.255.255 - - [31/Dec/2014:04:15:16 -0800] "GET /ccsetup.exe HTTP/1.1" 301 451 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SearchmetricsBot; http://www.xxxx.com/en/xxxx-bot/)"
```

How do I get rid of the output file path name, output file name and colon in the results?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Select-String` outputs an object from which you can pick off properties that you want.  The `Get-Member` command will show you these object members if you pipe into it e.g.:

```
Select-String -Path E:\Documents\combined0.txt -Pattern "GET /ccsetup\.exe" -AllMatches  | 
    Get-Member
```

One of those properties is `Line`. So try it this way:

```
Select-String -Path E:\Documents\combined0.txt -Pattern "GET /ccsetup\.exe" -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.Line} > E:\Documents\combined3.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

As usual powershell returns things as objects, by default select-string returns several properties including LineNumber, Filename, etc; the one you want with the data in is just called "Line".  So no need for anything fancy, just pipe it to "select line".

Eg:

```
Select-String "bla" filename.txt | select-object -ExpandProperty Line | out-file E:\bla_text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for (sub)strings rather than patterns, using the `-like` operator might be a better approach, performance-wise and with respect to ease-of-use.

```
$searchString = 'GET /ccsetup.exe'

Get-Content 'E:\Documents\combined0.txt' |
  ? { $_ -like "*$searchString*" } |
  Set-Content 'E:\Documents\combined3.txt'
```

If you do need pattern matches, you can easily replace the `-like` operator with the `-match` operator:

```
$pattern = 'GET /ccsetup\.exe'

Get-Content 'E:\Documents\combined0.txt' |
  ? { $_ -match $pattern } |
  Set-Content 'E:\Documents\combined3.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution:

```
PS> type .\test.txt
abc 
abc123 
xyz 
xyz123

PS> $(Select-String "123" .\test.txt).Line
abc123 
xyz123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content E:\Documents\combined0.txt | Select-String -Pattern "GET /ccsetup\.exe" -AllMatches
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# define your search path
$files = Get-ChildItem "./some_path"


for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    # loop through files in search folder
    $x=Select-String -Path $files[$i].FullName -Pattern "whatYouSearch"
    # retrieve the info with the option Line
    $out=$x.Line 
    # echo to output file (append)
    $out >> result.csv
}
```

Comment: Hey Paul, it is a different approach to the same question. Plus you have the loop variable $i in the control flow,  so that you can implement conditions to pipe/append/initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and wanted a simpler method of filtering out the exact text. I used  "| select-object -ExpandProperty Line" at the end of "Select-String -Path C:\Temp\AccountLockoutPolicy.Txt -Pattern 'ResetLockoutCount ='" and it removed the path and the line number. I like simple!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

`MatchInfo.Path` is writable property

```
$lines=Select-String '100.79.0.144' -LiteralPath (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath

foreach ($l in $lines) {
    $l.Path = ''
    $l # output to pipeline
}

# pipeline variant
$lines | % { $_.Path = ''; $_ }
```

Output

```
:13402:ssh runner@100.79.0.144
:13403:ssh runner@100.79.0.144 ls
:14197:Search-History 100.79.0.144
```